# Wrong urls generated by JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In my style.css file I use `#{resource}` to generate urls to images. The problem is that sometimes those urls are generated incorrectly. For example I use this `background: url("#{resource['default:img/contact/contact.png']};") #cd4c0a no-repeat` to generate background image. In most cases url is generated correctly and looks like this `background: url("/javax.faces.resource/img/contact/contact.png.xhtml?ln=default") #cd4c0a` but sometimes urls are empty and looks like this `url("")`. Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

My app works on openshift (openshift.redhat.com) server and uses Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0).

Comment: does it happens in the same css file?

Comment: Yes. I've got only one css file.

Comment: try to run it locally.... maybe its some issues with JSF2 and OpenShift... maybe its something to do with caching...

Comment: Clearing the cache helped but I still don't know why url's are empty.

Comment: Try to add `exception-handler-factory` to get better logging... maybe there are some exception that you don't see...